# PHP fails to access the docker socket via curl

Tags: php, docker, guzzle

My Code fails to reach the Docker Socket

```
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $test = $client->request('GET','http://v1.40/containers/json',[
        'curl' => [CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH => '/var/run/docker.sock']
    ]);
```

I only get a generic cURL error 7 from that and I´ve checked that the socket is available and working inside the Container with the cURL command from the cmd. Its only when i try to connect via PHP it fails ominously and frankly im out of ideas.

Comment: do you have the module curl installed ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes curl is installed and a request to google is successful

Comment: `working inside the Container with the cURL command from the cmd` For clarity and future readers please add that command and output to the question.

Answer (score 1):

So just in case someone stumbles upon this in the future and has the same or a similar problem.

Guzzle was not the problem in this case but phpfpm. I did not realize that the phpfpm workers in the official php docker image used the www-data user by default. The way I used is to change the user in the www.conf (default `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` in docker)

```
user = root
group = root
```

you will have to append the `-R` flag to the run command to allow running the workers as root.

Comment: It's not a good idea to work around permission problems by escalating priviledges, and rarely, a good idea to run php processes as root - [here's a reference](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/non-root-docker-containers-linas-zvirblis/). If this is in a production system it's worth finding a different solution, it's not clear from the question or answer what specifically running as root fixes/avoids (please edit the question/answer to clarify).

Answer (score 0):

`/var/run/docker.sock` belongs to the `docker` group. In order to interact with it, simply add the user that the PHP process runs as, e.g. `www-data`, to the group.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker www-data
```

This avoids escalating to `root` directly, but comes with its own set of dangers. See the Docker documentaion on [Linux post-install](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) and [security](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface).